# What are some interesting real-world applications of metrics?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, applications

I'm looking for ideas of real-world applications of different types of metrics/distances — especially (but not only) taxicab and railway metrics. By "real-world" I mean something that directly impacts our lives, i.e. not mathematical applications such as "solving systems of linear equations".

Examples:

- Taxicab metric helps first responders assess how long it takes to reach the destination.
- Hamming distance helps find genetic mutations.

Thank you!

Comment: Distance in a graph such as the permutahedron to give a content about "to which extend two permutations differ"

Comment: On an edge-weighted graph a distance can be define as the minimal weight of all loo-free paths between two points. This is the distance that we use to find the shortest connection between two cities on a roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

Different metrics such as Manhattan distance (taxicab metric) can help in implementing heuristics for AI. A simple example might be as follows:

In an 8-puzzle (n-puzzle) using the taxicab metric to implement a heuristic which would make AI decide which move is better to play by measuring the Manhattan distances of tiles to where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the ones you mention, a few quick ones that come to mind at the moment:

Euclidean metric: usual real-world notion of spatial distance

Discrete metric: captures whether you are in the same location as another or not

[Wasserstein metric (earth mover's distance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance): the cheapest way to transform one pile of dirt into another, where cost of moving dirt is amount of dirt to be moved times distance to be moved. It is a way to quantify distances between probability distributions and as such, has several [applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Applications) (see [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/arjovsky17a/arjovsky17a.pdf) for applications in machine learning).

[Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance): the distance it would take me to travel between two sets in a zero-sum game I play with an adversary, where my adversary moves first and chooses my origin in one of the two sets to maximize my distance travelled and I move second and choose my destination in the other set to minimize my distance travelled. It is a way to quantify distances between sets and has applications in [computer vision/computer graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Applications).

Answer (score 0):

- Does GPS count? The system calculates distance by including space-time curvature, and thus by tweaking Euclidean distance. This is one of the most important every day application of Einstein's General Relativity.
- Neural networks. Metrics are of course deeply hidden in the theory. By [the universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) every continuous function can be approximated by a neural network with arbitrary precision. Meaning for every continuous function there's a neural network arbitrarily close to it. This has deep implications in the digital world, where nowadays neural networks are almost everywhere, even inside CPUs.

Comment: GPS distance sounds interesting. Could you share some references? I haven't found anything about that.

Comment: @Paula read more about Schwarzschild metric. I'm not exactly sure about details, and it seems that in practice GPS does calculations somewhere between Newtonian and Einsteins physics. Still, it is an important concept.